# How to use stripe.js with form that contains additional data?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, stripe-payments, django-formwizard

I made a huge Django form for user subscription to a paying service. It contains user data, user preferences, and user payments infos.

As you may know, [stripe.js is intended to work this way](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms#sending-the-form-to-your-server):

- If credit cards infos are wrong, error is displayed in JS. The submit
  doesn't occur, and so, the page is not reloaded.
- If credit cards infos are right, then the form is submit to the Django server, then the page is reloaded.
- Note that during the process, credit card infos are not sent to Django server (that's the whole purpose).

It seems it has been thought to be used on credit card form only (with no additional data). As a result, here what's happening when submitting my form:

- If credit-card data is RIGHT but other data is WRONG, the Django page is reload with other data field filled, and with credit-card data **empty** (it's absolutely normal since credit card data is never sent to Django server, contrary to other data).

**The problem is that I don't want to force my user to re-enter credit cards informations if they made a mistake somewhere else in the form.**

I do understand why all of this occurs but is there a way to solve this?
I suppose Django form-wizards could be one way, it is? Is there a simpler one?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: stripe.js is fine if you're only dealing with a simple payment. You're going to need to do one of two things: Ajax your entire form or use the Stripe Python API to validate and charge the card. I would skip stripe.js entirely in this use case.

Comment: How can I skip stripe.js without transmitting credit card info to my server?

Comment: You don't need stripe.js to send data to Stripe. They provide a Python library where you can send all of your data on the server side: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python

Comment: But you agree that in Python in my server, if a I write somehing like `stripe.Token.create(card={ "number": '4242424242424242',...` that would mean the card number would had been sent to my server.

Comment: It has been sent to stripe. You don't have to do that until your form is valid, and validating the card data is something you can do as part of a Django form.

Comment: Sorry I really don't understand. How could the user transmit it's credit card data using Python without using my server??? Only javascript can allow the data in the client web browser to be sent directly to stripe without transiting by my server! I thought it was the whole purpose of stripe.js

Comment: It will go through your server via a form, but given that you need to validate other data, using the Stripe Python API is really your only choice, unless you want to extend stripe.js

Comment: Thanks for your help. I finally used wizard-form (step by step form) to use Stripe.js. It allows the user to send credit card data directly to stripe server, and the server get back a token (I use Python API at this moment).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Django expert, so I can't provide explicit code here, but the credit card data is sent to Stripe (via Stripe.js) and a representative token is returned. That token is stored in a hidden form input so that it goes to the server-side code.

In your situation, I'd be inclined to re-store the token in the hidden form input, and indicate that the credit card has already been taken. If you dynamically adjust your validation logic accordingly, you could then not re-require the credit card when it's the other information that was the problem.

Cheers,
Larry

PS I work on Support at Stripe.